# Left click not working in login page

Tags: macos, mac, mouse

I bought a Mac Mini M2 to which I associated Logitech peripherals.
For a month everything worked correctly, but now I've been experiencing some problems with the mouse.

This mouse has two side buttons, in addition to the classic two clicks.  Well, **only on the login page**, the classic left click to select the user is no longer recognized.
I have to use one of the two side keys.

Once logged in, the mouse starts working properly again.
I can't figure out the reason for this problem, I haven't installed anything weird and everything was working fine until the other day.
I use the Logitech G HUB program for color customization, but I've used it since day one and it has never given me any problems.  And I don't think before login it loads and runs.

Do you have any idea?
Thank you.
The mouse is a Logitech G203 and the Mac is a Mac Mini with M2 Silicon.

Comment: Boot into Safe Mode, which will disable all 3rd party software. If your mouse works properly, in this mode, it’s something you installed.

Comment: Is your keyboard not working too?